# Deeplink issue with IOS 10.3

Tags: php, ios, deep-linking

I am facing the issue mentioned in the below link.

https://blog.branch.io/the-problem-with-apple-app-store-redirects-on-safari-ios-10-3/

Below is my PHP code:

```
var websiteLink = 'https://itunes.apple.com/';
var deepLink = "xxxx://dev/one?action="+action+"&shopId="+shopId;
    var now = new Date().valueOf();
     setTimeout(function () {
          if (new Date().valueOf() - now > 5000) return;
          window.location = websiteLink;
     }, 100);
     window.location = deepLink;
```

This is working fine in the os less than 10.3. I am getting address not valid issue in Safari. Also this issue happened only on the Safari browser, Its works fine on Chrome.

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when the user updated their iOS devices to version 10.3. According to this website [branch.io](https://blog.branch.io/the-problem-with-apple-app-store-redirects-on-safari-ios-10-3/), this was Apple solution to fix some security holes.

To enable deep links feature for your app you need to launch an update, because one of the reasons that deep links stopped working was of an expired provisional profile.